# Mvn Test cmd line Build Failure, Test Works in Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, selenium, automated-tests

This is the circumstance. I am an QA Automation Engineer and right now I am being charged with setting up our CI framework in Jenkins but right now I am having issues with Maven. I am getting this error below when I try to run the mvn test command. However the tests work flawlessly in eclipse when run as maven test.

```
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configur
ator@3830f1c0
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configur
ator@bd8db5a
Tests run: 16, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 14, Time elapsed: 0.66 sec <<< F
AILURE!
beforeTest(fcstestingsuite.fsnrgn.LoginTest)  Time elapsed: 0.442 sec  <<< FAILU
RE!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set b
y the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https:/
/github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be dow
nloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:19
9)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(Drive
rService.java:109)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDrive
rService.java:32)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExe
cutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(Driver
Service.java:296)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(C
hromeDriverService.java:88)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:116)

        at fcstestingsuite.fsnrgn.LoginTest.beforeTest(LoginTest.java:54)


Results :

Failed tests:   beforeTest(fcstestingsuite.fsnrgn.LoginTest): The path to the dr
iver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for
more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver.
The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis
.com/index.html

Tests run: 16, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 14
```

As you can see it is related to my chrome system property/path. In my project I have a test package and page object package. I set my chrome system property in the object class and import that class into the test class which works fine in eclipse. I'm not quite sure why Maven is having an issue with this. See sample object and test class below

Page Class

```
package pageobjectfactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.testng.Assert;
// URL = http://www.ourfsn.com/myfsn/

public class Ourfsnlogin {

    @FindBy(id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbxUname")
    WebElement login;
    @FindBy(id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbxPword")
    WebElement password;
    @FindBy(id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit")
    WebElement submit;
    @FindBy(name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rptAccounts$ctl01$AccountSwitch")
    WebElement PETSMARTUS;
    @FindBy(name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rptAccounts$ctl02$AccountSwitch")
    WebElement PETSMARTCAD;
    @FindBy(name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rptAccounts$ctl03$AccountSwitch")
    WebElement PETSMARTPR;
    @FindBy(id="ctl00_lblTopLogin")
    WebElement PETSMARTUSASSERT;
    @FindBy(id="ctl00_lblTopLogin")
    WebElement PETSMARTCAASSERT;
    @FindBy(id="ctl00_lblTopLogin")
    WebElement PETSMARTPRASSERT;
    @FindBy(id="ctl00_Menu1_16")
    WebElement LogoutButton;


    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\dmohamed\\Documents\\Testing Environment\\Testing Environment\\Web Drivers\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver chromedriver = null; new ChromeDriver();


        driver= chromedriver;


    }


    //Send user name in textbox 
    public void sendUserName(String strUsername){
        login.sendKeys("ebluth");}
    public void sendUserNameServiceCenter(String strUsername){
        login.sendKeys("servicecenter");}
    public void sendUserNameSP(String strUsername){
        login.sendKeys("4328701");
    }
    //Send Password
    public void sendPassword(String strPassword){
        password.sendKeys("password");}




    //submitting credentials 
    public void clicksubmit(){
        submit.click();}
    //Checking US PAge 
    public void USAssertion(){
        PETSMARTUS.isEnabled();
    }
    //Checking CAD page 
    public void CAAssertion(){
        PETSMARTCAD.isEnabled();}
    //Checking PR Page 
    public void PRAssertion(){
        PETSMARTPR.isEnabled();}
    //click us link

    //Checking US PAge 
    public void USclick(){
        PETSMARTUS.click();
    }
    //Checking CAD page 
    public void CAclick(){
        PETSMARTCAD.click();}
    //Checking PR Page 
    public void PRclick(){
        PETSMARTPR.click();}

    //Click on
    public void USPageValidation(){
        Assert.assertTrue(PETSMARTUSASSERT.getText().contains("PETM-US"), "Incorrect Page [US,CA,PR]");

    }
    public void PRPageValidation(){
        Assert.assertTrue(PETSMARTPRASSERT.getText().contains("PETM-PR"),"Incorrect Page [US,CA,PR]");
    }
    public void CAPageValidation(){
        Assert.assertTrue(PETSMARTCAASSERT.getText().contains("PETM-CN"),"Incorrect Page [US,CA,PR]");
    }
    //Log out 

    public void Logout (){
        LogoutButton.click();



    }}

Test Class 
package fcstestingsuite.fsnrgn;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import pageobjectfactory.Ourfsnlogin;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.AjaxElementLocatorFactory;

public class LoginTest {
    static WebDriver driver;
    Ourfsnlogin LoginPage; 

    @Test (priority=1)
    public void USPageTest() {
        LoginPage.sendUserName("ebluth");
        LoginPage.sendPassword("password");
        LoginPage.clicksubmit();
        LoginPage.USclick();
        LoginPage.USPageValidation();
    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void CAPageTest(){
        LoginPage.sendUserName("ebluth");
        LoginPage.sendPassword("password");
        LoginPage.clicksubmit();
        LoginPage.CAclick();
        LoginPage.CAPageValidation();
    }


    @Test (priority=3)
    public void PRPageTest(){
        LoginPage.sendUserName("ebluth");
        LoginPage.sendPassword("password");
        LoginPage.clicksubmit();
        LoginPage.PRclick();
        LoginPage.PRPageValidation();
    }


    @AfterMethod 
    public void aftermethod(){
        LoginPage.Logout();
    }



    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {
        Ourfsnlogin.driver=new ChromeDriver();
        //setting global explicit wait 
        PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 20), this);
        Ourfsnlogin.driver.get("http://www.ourfsn.com/myfsn");
        //initiating elements in page factory 
        LoginPage= PageFactory.initElements(Ourfsnlogin.driver, Ourfsnlogin.class);

    }

    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest() {
        Ourfsnlogin.driver.quit();


    }

}
```

Comment: So maybe the `webdriver.chrome.driver` property is set in your Eclipse environment, but not on your OS, so the command-line doesn't pick it up. Check your Eclipse preferences, I'd start by the Maven run configurations.

Comment: How are you running your tests? through xml?

Comment: Yes I was running the test through xml. After doing some digging I found that you are to put the path to the driver.exe file in you environmental variable PATH. So I did that, not 100% sure if that did anything ( did that and some other actions) but I suspect it did.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your tests seems incorrect.  You have a main method in the LoginPage - which is doing driver instantiation. Where is the main method being called from?  Your beforetest also has a driver instantiation code which is called by testng but there you are not setting the chromedriver property.

Ideally the driver instantiation code should be written at one place and be consumed from the rest of the testcases.

Comment: This was the issue, I never called in the method that set the system property, once I did that my mvn test cmd worked fine and the driver instantiation in the test code was redundant. Thanks a lot !